# Does the Facebook C# SDK depend on cookies on the server?

Tags: asp.net, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

I'm using the [Facebook C# SDK](http://csharpsdk.org/) and am trying to figure out exactly how it works.  I actually use an AJAX web method to lookup the Facebook account details based on the authenticated user ID, which looks something like this:

```
if (response.status === "connected")
{
   KitchenPC.LogonFB(response.authResponse.userID, checkResult, facebookError);
}
```

On the server side, the LogonFB web method does something like:

```
Client = new FacebookClient(applicationId, applicationSecret);
var result = Client.Get(path) as IDictionary<string, object>;

UserId = Int64.Parse((String)result["id"]);
Name = result["name"] as String;
FirstName = result["first_name"] as String;
LastName = result["last_name"] as String;
Location = result.ContainsKey("location") ? result["location"] as String : "";
Gender = result.ContainsKey("gender") ? result["gender"] as String : "";
Email = result["email"] as String;
```

Where `path` is the user ID passed in from the client.

**My Question:**

I'm switching from ASP.NET Web Service to WCF, and WCF does not support cookies.  In fact, `HttpContext.Current` will be null within the WCF pipeline.  I was under the impression that the Facebook C# SDK *depended* on the `fbm_` and `fmsr_` cookies being passed in on the request, which would be used to validate the session with the Facebook server.  However, much to my surprise, the `.Get()` call still works, and user information is returned.  I also dug through the SDK source code and nowhere in it do I find references to `HttpContext.Current`.

Does the Facebook C# SDK work completely independently of cookies?  Does this mean that all I need is the user's Facebook ID, and as long as they've previously approved my app ID, I can grab information about their account?

I just want to make sure I'm not doing anything wrong, and I'm not going to run into trouble in production.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pass the constructor with appId and appSecret, it will auto set the access token as app access token using `string.Concat(appId, '|', appSecret)`. That constructor has been removed in newer version of the sdk. https://github.com/facebook-csharp-sdk/facebook-csharp-sdk/issues/103

Set it to null if you don't want the access token.

```
Client = new FacebookClient(applicationId, applicationSecret);
Client.AccessToken = null;
var result = Client.Get(path) as IDictionary<string, object>;
```

Comment: no. it is based on Client Framework so there is no System.Web.dll reference. It does have the capability to parse the signed request but even for this you would need to pass the signed_request manually. fb.ParseSignedRequest(Request.Params["signed_request"], "appSecret"). It does not support parsing cookies.

Comment: Ok, great.  That answers my question!